# Angle between two points and calculating the rotation

Tags: java, vector, rotation, libgdx

so I'm currently programming a little game in Java with libGDX.

I want the players texture to directly rotate to the mouse position. 
Unfortunately my code doesn't work, and I have absolutely no idea why not.

So, I call this method in the Update method of the player:

```
private void CalculateRotation()
{
    rotation = Position.angle(input.getTranslatedMousePos());
}
```

The Position is just a Vector2 with the players position. 
I get the translatedMousePos like this:

```
public Vector2 getTranslatedMousePos()
{
    Vector3 v = camera.unproject(new Vector3(MousePos.x, MousePos.y, 0));

    return new Vector2(v.x, v.y);
}
```

while MousePos is determined by the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    MousePos = new Vector2(screenX, screenY);
    return false;
}
```

I draw the players sprite like this:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
spriteBatch.draw(new TextureRegion(txt), Position.x, Position.y, (float)(size.x * 0.5), (float)(size.y * 0.5), size.x, size.y, 1.0f, 1.0f, rotation);
}
```

Unfortunately the sprite turns, but in no way pointing to the cursor.

Following things I figured out yet:

- spriteBatch.draw(...,rotation) accepts degrees and Vector2.angle gives the angle in degrees
- the translatedMousePos seems to be right, I figured that out by hovering over the players sprite (which is at (1000|-1000)) and "printing" the translatedMousePos, it was the same

Thank you for taking your time and helping me! :)

Comment: To work out an angle between two *lines*, you need a minimum of three points.

Comment: Try `rotation = input.getTranslatedMousePos().sub(Position).nor().angle();`