# Rotation of sprite completely off in libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to get my sprites arm to rotate and point exactly to where the mouse is on screen. The sprite for the arm is obviously separate from the other sprites. This is what the arm sprite looks like and i wrote the dimensions of it

[image: Arm]

and in the game it is attached to the shoulder of my players torso and I make the sprite flip depending on if he is moving left or right. In order to rotate the arm I have this code in the `InputListener`

```
    float mouseX, mouseY, rot;
@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    mouseX = screenX;
    mouseY = Math.abs(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY);
    cam.unproject(new Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0));
    rot = MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * MathUtils.atan2((float)mouseY - (float)player.getPosition().y, (float)mouseX - (float)player.getPosition().x);
    if (rot < 0) rot += 360;
    player.setObjectRotation(rot);

    tmp.x = screenX;
    tmp.y = screenY;
    tmp.z = 0;
```

If the mouse is on the left of the player he and the arm flips and I want the arm to only rotate about 180 from the images origin so that you can aim and shoot both ways you are looking but this code doesn't seem to work it makes the arm rotate like crazy. Any help with this would be extremely appreciated for my math skills are really lacking in order to accomplish this.

Comment: i deleted the answer as it doesnot solves your purpose will put the new answer soon

Comment: (float)mouseY - (float)player.getPosition().y,-player.getwidth()/2) 
same dor x also , might wanna give it a chance,I dont have my system right now so i cant test and tell u for sure, Sorry for that

Comment: @KumarSaurabh I can't tell 100% if it worked because it spins super fast, could it be because the center of the image is the center of the arm and not at the shoulder where it should rotate from? And should the width be of the arm image width of player width

Comment: speed should not have to do anything with the origin of the image, origin just decides the point around which the the image, if u want to rotate your image only once just use sprite.rotate() instead of setRotation()

Comment: @KumarSaurabh setRotation() made it slow and be able to see it but now it only points to it if the mouse on the upper side, when u go lower the arm is just straight out and you can only really see a difference if the mouse moves left or right not up or down

Comment: try printing the rotation values, then maybe we can be sure that the values of rotation are coming correct from the equation

Comment: @KumarSaurabh The rotation ranges from 260 to 290 when moving left and right and nothing changes while going up and down, well it changes about 4

Comment: you might have a look here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412383/angle-between-two-points-and-calculating-the-rotation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93040/discussion-between-luke-and-kumar-saurabh).